# ArrayList, print only the value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a `contactList = new ArrayList<>();` where I store information in this format: `"name", value_for_name`.

I populate my contactList inside this function:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);



            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

                    // looping through All Results
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String icon = c.getString("icon");
                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");



                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        // contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("name", name);
                        // contact.put("email", icon);


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);

                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }
```

The problem is that when I try to print a value:

```
System.out.println(contactList.get(position));
```

The output is in this format:
{name="Foo"}

I only want to print `Foo`
I tried also with: `System.out.println(String.valueOf(contactList.get(position)));`
but I always get the whole string: `{name="Foo"}`

Can you help me, please?
Do I really need to parse the string?

Comment: `System.out.println(contactList.get(position).getName())`.

Comment: "Do I really need to parse the string?" No, you should only ever think to do this as a last resort. It's brittle.

Comment: `contactList.get(position).get("name")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
System.out.println(contactList.get(position).get("name"));
```

I see you have a hashmap into an array list so you want to get the object from "X" position from array and after that get the value from the hashmap by property name.